# Trying to add more than one Patient into my Patient table in Netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans

I have an enhanced for loop that loops through my array of Patients.

Inside this loop I have an insert statement that's used to insert the patient's number, name, address and phone number.

However, when there's more than one patient in the array, the previous patients get over written in the database. Is there any way for me to get to the next row of the table so that I don't over write all the previous entries?

Here is the method that I'm using.

```
public void databaseSave( ArrayList <Patient> pList )
    {

    try
    {
        String name = "Shaun";
        String pass = "Shaun";
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DentistDatabase";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, name, pass);

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        //Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        System.out.println("Before the delete");


        String query = "DELETE "
                    +  "FROM SHAUN.PATIENT";


        System.out.println("After the delete");


        stmt.executeUpdate(query);


        String select = "SELECT * FROM SHAUN.PATIENT";

        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(select);


        System.out.println("Before loop");

        for ( Patient p: pList )
        {

            patientInsertSQL = "Insert Into SHAUN.PATIENT VALUES (" + p.getPatientNum() + ", '"
            + p.getPatientName() + "', '" + p.getPatientAddress() + "', '"
            + p.getPatientPhone() + "')";


            System.out.println("In the loop!");

        }


        int res = stmt.executeUpdate(patientInsertSQL);

        System.out.println(res);


        stmt.close();
        result.close();
        con.commit();

        System.out.println("After Loop and close");

    }
    catch (SQLException err)
    {
        System.out.print(err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: The execute should be done within the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You have to execute the query on every iteration or use **SQL Batch Insert**.

```
for ( Patient p: pList )
        {
            patientInsertSQL = "Insert Into SHAUN.PATIENT VALUES (" + p.getPatientNum() + ", '"+ p.getPatientName() + "', '" + p.getPatientAddress() + "', '"
            + p.getPatientPhone() + "')";
        int res = stmt.executeUpdate(patientInsertSQL);

}
```

Or **[SQL Batch Insert](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/)**:

```
for(Patient p:pList) {
PatientInsertSQL = "Insert into patient Values(x,y,z)";
stmnt.addBatch(query);
}
stmnt.executeBatch();
```

BTW, to avoid [**SQL Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) use [**PreparedStatement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) rather than Statement

Answer (score 1):

The statement `int res = stmt.executeUpdate(patientInsertSQL);` should be within the for loop.